# Solving a System of Linear Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Step-by-Step, What is the solution for this system of linear equations?

> $7x + 2y -5z = -18$
>
> $x + 5y - 3z = -40$
>
> $2x -y -9z = -26$

The correctly answer is (x = 2, y = -6, z = 4).

Comment: @AustinMohr I don't know why it didn't display. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Well,use Gauss-Jordan...(use fractions ,if you think it´s better)

1. Divide row 1 by 7
2. Subtract row 1 from row 2
3. Subtract (2 × row 1) from row 3
4. Divide row 2 by 4.714
5. Subtract (-1.571 × row 2) from row 3
6. Divide row 3 by -8.333
7. Subtract (-0.714 × row 3) from row 1
8. Subtract (-0.485 × row 3) from row 2
9. Subtract (0.286 × row 2) from row

Ten you will get in your matrix,that in this point is in a reduced row echelon form,the answer you already had:first line is (1 0   0   2),second line(0    1   0   -6), third line (0  0   1   4).The one´s correnspond to x , y and z.

Comment: It usually best to write those decimals as fractions. Else, the results are wrong.

Comment: Also, on this site, it helps if you use LaTex.  Just an fyi, so you can get a better result when you given an answer.

Comment: I answered this one when I created the account,so I didn't know Latex very well.I know better now,way better.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to matrices as Austin does in his answer, you can first multiply the last equation ($2x-y-9z=-26$) by an appropriate constant so that when you add it to the first equation ($7x+2y-5z=-18$), the $y$ variable is canceled. Repeat the process but this time add the last equation to the second equation ($x+5y-3z=-40$). Now you're left with 2 equations in two variables. Use this same process to multiply one of the equations by a constant so that when you add then two together, you eliminate the $x$ variable. Finally you have a single linear equation to solve for $z$. Once you have a value for $z$, plug that into your original equations and look for a way to multiply one equation by a constant to make a variable disappear.

I do recommend using matrices over this method. This takes longer, looks messier,and the process isn't as algorithmic as using Gaussian elimination.

**EDIT** I thought it might be useful to show you how to set this up using Gaussian elimination. At each step the indicated operation will use $R_1$ for row 1, $R_2$ for row 2, and $R_3$ for row 3.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&5&-3&-40\\2&-1&-9&-26\\7&2&-5&-18
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{-2R_1+R_2} \begin{bmatrix}
1&5&-3&-40\\0&-11&-3&54\\7&2&-5&-18
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{-7R_1+R_3} \begin{bmatrix}
1&5&-3&-40\\0&-11&-3&54\\0&-33&16&262
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{-3R_2+R_3} \begin{bmatrix}
1&5&-3&-40\\0&-11&-3&54\\0&0&25&100
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{25}R_3} \begin{bmatrix}
1&5&-3&-40\\0&-11&-3&54\\0&0&1&4
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{\text{skipping steps}} \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&2\\0&1&0&-2\\0&0&1&4
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a corresponding matrix equation. Let
$$
A = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
7 & 2 & -5\\
1 &5 & -3\\
2 & -1 & -9
\end{array}
\right],
$$
$$
X = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}
\right],
$$
and
$$
B = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
-18\\
-40\\
-26
\end{array}
\right].
$$
You should convince yourself that the system of linear equations is exactly the same as the matrix equation
$$
AX = B.
$$
Multiplying both sides *on the left* by $A^{-1}$ (matrix multiplication does not commute) gives
$$
A^{-1}AX = A^{-1}B
$$
which simplifies to
$$
X = A^{-1}B.
$$
You can use a calculator to evaluate this last line.

Note $A^{-1}$ may not always exist (you will know this is the case if your calculator gives a message like "singular matrix"). In this situation, you have either an inconsistent system (no solutions) or a dependent system (infinitely-many solutions). To handle these kinds of systems, you should resort to Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Answer (score 0):

We tag the equations for convenience:

$$\tag 1 7x + 2y -5z = -18$$

$$\tag 2 x + 5y - 3z = -40$$

$$\tag 3 2x -y -9z = -26$$

We first perform $(1)-7\times(2)$ which gives

$$\tag 4-33y+16z=262$$

Now we perform $2\times(1)-7\times (3)$, which gives

$$\tag 5 11  y+ {53}  z=146 $$

Now we make $11\times(4)+33\times (5)$, which gives

$$1925z=7700$$

so $z=7700/1925=4$. And now it's just a "chain reaction".

Note we chose the constants so that the first term cancelled out. This method is called Gaussian elimination, or Gauss-Jordan method.